When did Delphi start backing up FDConnectionDefs.ini
Often, after installing a new version of Delphi, I have to recreate all my databases in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\FireDAC\FDConnectionDefs.ini.  However, after installing Delphi 12, I went to do this, and there were several backup files (e.g. FDConnectionDefs-Tue27082024_160735.34.bak).  After renaming the latest one of these, I had my latest changes.
Which version of Delphi started doing this, or is one of the plug-ins I have installed doing this (cnWizards)?

There is a corresponding issue in Quality Portal which has a fix version of 11 Alexandria: dissapeared connections in data explorer after Tokyo install
